# ASP CreateUserWizard Membership provider registration user validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, membership-provider, createuserwizard

Im a newbie to the world of ASP and C#, I have just created my first Registration form using the CreateUserWizard Membership Provider and set up the validators which work great, Appart from the "Username". If the user name is taken the page simply refreshes and no error appears would be realy greatfull if somone could point out where I might be going wrong.

Here is my current code :

**SCRIPT**

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* User is created and setting extra parameters to profile */
    TextBox UserNameTextBox = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName");
    string username = UserNameTextBox.Text;

    MembershipUser User = Membership.GetUser(username);
    umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member.Member member = new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member.Member((int)User.ProviderUserKey);

    /* Here you can access properties for the member */
    umbraco.cms.businesslogic.property.Property FullNameProperty = member.getProperty("fullname"); // Property alias
    TextBox FullNameTextBox = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("FullName");
    FullNameProperty.Value = FullNameTextBox.Text;

    Roles.AddUserToRole(CreateUserWizard1.UserName, "NuneatonMember");
}
protected void CreateUserWizard1_ContinueButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("/member-area.aspx");
}
```

CONTENT

```
<form runat="server">
 <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" OnContinueButtonClick="CreateUserWizard1_ContinueButtonClick" OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser" runat="server">
     <WizardSteps>
         <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>

    First Name :<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="FullName" CssClass="user_info"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="FullNameVal" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FullName" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br/>

    Last Name :<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="LastName" CssClass="user_info"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="LastNameVal" runat="server" ControlToValidate="LastName" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br/>

    Username :<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="UserName" CssClass="user_info"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameVal" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br/>

    E-mail :<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="Email" CssClass="user_info"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailVal" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="valRegEx" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email" ValidationExpression=".*@.*\..*" ErrorMessage="* is not a valid e-mail address." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" display="dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <br/>

    Password :<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="Password" CssClass="user_info"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordVal" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br/>

    Confirm Password :<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="ConfirmPassword" CssClass="user_info"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PConfirmVal" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br/>

    <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" ErrorMessage="Foul: Password and Confirmation Password do not match. Fix them."></asp:CompareValidator>

    <asp:literal runat="server" enableviewstate="true" id="FailureText"></asp:literal>

   </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
         <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server"></asp:CompleteWizardStep>
     </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Comment: Are you specifying in your web.config Membership Provider settings that the email address will be unique?

Comment: <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="GeneralMember" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
        <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an error handler.

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" 
      OnContinueButtonClick="CreateUserWizard1_ContinueButtonClick"  
      OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser" runat="server" 
      OnCreateUserError="createUserWizard_CreateUserError">
```

And an example of how you could implement it.

```
protected void createUserWizard_CreateUserError(object sender, CreateUserErrorEventArgs arguments)
{
    LogCreateUserError(arguments.CreateUserError, "no user info");
}

 private void LogCreateUserError(MembershipCreateStatus status, string username)
{
    string reasonText = status.ToString();

    switch (status)
    {
        case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
        case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateProviderUserKey:
        case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:

            reasonText = "The user details you entered are already registered.";
            break;

        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidProviderUserKey:
        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion:
        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName:
        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:

            reasonText = string.Format("The {0} provided was invalid.", status.ToString().Substring(7));
            break;
        default:
            reasonText = "Due to an unknown problem, we were not able to register you at this time";
            break;

    }
   //DO whatever with it.. ....

}
```

Comment: Thanks Nix That would work, might be silly question but how would I output the reasonText to a (HTML) validation message.

Comment: @NikG Please comment if you think something is wrong with the content and let the poster fix it.

Comment: @Rotem - no worries, I'll do that in the future. It may also be worth them adding this at the bottom which will answer Yardsermister's question above:  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reasonText)){
         var FailureText = (Literal)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("FailureText");
         FailureText.Text = reasonText;
    }